# SQL Server Objects (Schema Compare with Merge)

Tags: sql-server

We are trying to maintain two SQL environment, let's say Development and Staging. On Staging I did a bug fix on one stored procedure called for example SProc1, at the same time someone on development was doing some changes on the same sp. I need to apply the bug fix on development without losing the changes on development.

Using SQL Schema Compare on Visual Studio 2015 doesn't do a merge of code, it's just replace the version directly.

My question is, which other tools are on the market to maintain this kind of scenarios?

Comment: I assume you have some kind of source control (like TFS)? I'd say that code merging is a task for your source control system.

Comment: yes we are using TFS, but is there anything else we can use just for sql objects? I tried Redgate but they don't have a tool like that

Comment: Ok, we just check in our SP:s as text files and then TFS can do the merge. We have a separate deploy system för db-changes. I dont know how to help you with this.

Comment: I guess this is the only way, thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no correct answer here. You've created a conflict between environments and the only way to resolve this will be to compare the source of each version and merge the differences manually.

While strictly off-topic for Stack Overflow, I'd recommend an application called [Beyond Compare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) for all kinds of file comparisons. It does excel at text comparisons though.

Alternatively, you've mentioned that you are using TFS. Assuming the development changes have been checked in to a development branch, you could create a branch off this for the hotfix although from a previous check in, apply your changes, then merge back. This will present a conflict that will need manually rectifying much as per Beyond Compare, but then you will retain the conflict history in your version control.

**Edit**: the following gif explains the process better than I can:

[image]
[Source](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/articles/branching-strategies-with-tfvc)

Answer (score 5):

*Late answer, but I hope it will be useful to new readers*

I recently stumbled upon new free tool, [ApexSQL Compare](https://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_compare.aspx), that offers files and folders comparison and merging. Tool can integrate into SSMS/VS and looks like this:

[image: Merge view screenshot]

This tool will create merge script, which will include bug fix and changes on the same sp, but the script can only be executed manually. Also, to execute this script manually, CREATE PROCEDURE statement should be changed to ALTER PROCEDURE